# How to hook WooCommerce Categories Attribute filter widget into third party gadget?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a third party search gadget with my *WooCommerce* shop page code as below.

```
<div class="refineTools">
   <div class="regionFilter">
      <span class="label"><label>Region</label></span>
      <span class="input">
         <select>
            <option value="">--- All ---</option>
            <option value="Bali">Bali</option>
            <option value="Bohol">Bohol</option>
         </select>
      </span>
   </div>
**<strong>I want WooCommerce Categories Attribute Tab Here</strong>**
 </div>
```

How can I add WooCommerce Categories Attribute filter on above specific place? What’s the perfect hook to call below attribute code dynamically into above code?

```
<div id="woocommerce_layered_nav-12" class="widget woocommerce widget_layered_nav">
   <h4>Collections</h4>
   <select class="dropdown_layered_nav_setting">
      <option value="">Any Setting</option>
      <option value="absolute-beachfront">Absolute Beachfront</option>
      <option value="breathtaking-views">Breathtaking Views</option>
      <option value="celebrate-in-style">Celebrate in Style</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

As of now I am using below code to call Collection tab with static code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div.regionFilter').after('<div class="Collection"><span class="label"><label>Collection</label></span> <span class="input"> <select> <option value="---ALL---">---ALL---</option><option value="Beach Holiday">Beach Holiday</option><option value="Brand New">Brand New</option></select> </span></div>');}, 5000);
});
</script>
```

I want to call it dynamically so functionality also works. As of now, static code is showing collection tab in the perfect location, but functionality is not working because it's not calling dynamically.

To make it work, I want to use [product_category] shortcode in after function

```
$('div.locationsFilter').after('');
```